# Titre d'oeuvre dans un texte en italique

Tags: typographie

De manière générale, les [titres d’œuvres sont en italique](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/24371/la-typographie/mise-en-relief/italique/emploi-de-litalique-pour-les-titres-doeuvres-et-de-publications-periodiques). Mais que faire lorsque le texte est déjà en italique ? Faut-il mettre les titres d’œuvres en romain ou entre guillemets ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voici ce que dit le *[Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'imprimerie nationale](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexique_des_r%C3%A8gles_typographiques_en_usage_%C3%A0_l%27Imprimerie_nationale)* :

> Les noms propres œuvres littéraires [...] ou artistiques [...], de journaux ou de revues cités dans un ouvrage reproduisent en principe exactement la dénomination choisie par l'auteur ou le fondateur. Pour en marquer l'authenticité, on composera ces noms en *italique* (dans un texte en romain et *vice versa*)

Jean-Pierre Lacroux dit la même chose dans *[Orthotypographie](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/telegramme-troncation.html)* :

> Dans un texte en italique, les titres d’œuvres se composent en romain : *Pascal n’a jamais lu les* Provinciales *de Giraudoux*.

C'est la façon dont je procède et je crois que c'est ce qu'il y a de plus usuel. Mais j'ai déjà rencontré des titres mis entre guillemets quand le texte est en italique. Dans ce cas ce sont en principe des choix de l'éditeur.